# Ember: How to get values of a file returned at Route->Model

Tags: ember.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('rentals');
    }
});
```

The code above returns all rentals, say, 10 objects. Now, I want to get first, or last, or even multiple, but can't. Tried:

```
return this.get('store').findAll('rentals')[0];
return this.get('store').findAll('rentals').get(0);
return this.get('store').findAll('rentals').firstObject;
return this.get('store').findAll('rentals').slice(0, 2);
return this.get('store').findAll('rentals').splice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you try to execute this code? In controller? Then `this.get('model.firstObject')` should work.

In other situations - it probably won't as `findAll` returns a promise. So you should be sure to wait for this promise to resolve, for example:

```
this.get('store').findAll('rentals').then(loadedRentals => {
    // Here we have access to 'rental' objects

    loadedRentals.forEach(r => console.log(`Rental ${r} is fully loaded`));
}
```